# Pasar y Quitar valor de Checkboxs a input

Tags: javascript, html

Me podrían ayudar, tengo 3 checkbox y un input.

Al dar click en los checks pasa el valor al input, hasta ahi todo bien.

Lo que necesito es que cuando se desmarque un check se borre solo ese valor que se paso al input.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="campo.value += (this.checked) ? this.value:'' " value="Valor1" />
<input  type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" onclick="campo.value += (this.checked) ? this.value:'' " value="Valor2" />
<input  type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" onclick="campo.value += (this.checked) ? this.value:'' " value="Valor3" />

<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" />
```

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de agregar el valor del checkbox individual, cuando hagas clic revisa el estado de todos los checkbox para crear el resultado, a esto me refiero:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var text = document.getElementById('campo');

function checkboxClick(event) {
  var valor = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      valor += checkboxes[i].value;
    }
  }
  campo.value = valor;
}

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', checkboxClick);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Valor1" />
<input  type="checkbox" value="Valor2" />
<input  type="checkbox" value="Valor3" />

<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" />
```